# php shell_exec with sudo commands not working

Tags: php, sudoers

I have made a file test.php in (/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/test.php)
containing code

```
$data = shell_exec("sudo php -v"); 
var_dump($data);
```

but it gives me result **NULL**

I am using PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.1 (cli), so i have added line in /etc/sudoers file also

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/test.php
```

I have also tried by adding

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

But nothing seems to work. Please help

Comment: try a 'ls' command. Do you get anything?

Comment: It work with another command without sudo ?

Comment: yes ls is working.... actually commands starts with sudo not seems to working... as if i try **sudo ls** its not working but simple **ls** is working with shell_exec

Comment: ok run 'whoami' to check what user you are using

Comment: is this user in the sudoers? The best thing you can do is login to your server and execute the exacly command you are trying. Do you get any results?

Comment: @Rafael: is this user in the sudoers? how can i figure out sudoers user in file... can you please help ? thanks

Comment: u can check /etc/sudoers but if you run sudo -l what do you get?

Comment: olso try to add the user to sudo one more time 'sudo adduser <username> sudo'

Answer (score 3):

- Edit the sudoers file (with `visudo`) and add a rule that allows the web server user to run the command without a password.  For example:

  ```
  www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/script
  ```

  This will allow that particular user to call `sudo` on that particular script without being prompted for a password.
- Try specifying the entire path to the php binary.. `/usr/bin/php`, If you don't know it, find it using: `which php`

  ```
  $data = shell_exec("/usr/bin/php -v"); 
  var_dump($data);
  ```
- You can also check your php.ini restrict the available command set ?

  ```
  ; When safe_mode is on, only executables located in the safe_mode_exec_dir
  ; will be allowed to be executed via the exec family of functions.
  ; http://php.net/safe-mode-exec-dir
  safe_mode_exec_dir =
  ```

Comment: I had tried with visudo already as i had mentioned in my question also. nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You should change minimum uid/gid for mpm_itk module:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/modules.d/00_mpm_itk.conf
<IfDefine MPM_ITK>
LoadModule mpm_itk_module modules/mpm_itk.so
#  LimitUIDRange 1000 2000
#  LimitGIDRange 1000 2000
  LimitUIDRange 0 2000
  LimitGIDRange 0 2000
</IfDefine>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo adduser USERNAME

sudo usermod -aG sudo USERNAME
```

you need to create a new user in ubuntu if you are login with default credentials then switch to a newly created user.

Here you just need to replace USERNAME with your new one

```
su - USERNAME
```

in last you can use every command with sudo

```
shell_exec('echo "yourpassword" | sudo -u yourusername -S | sudo --version')
```