# PHP: shell_exec rejects password for a shell command but works in shell

Tags: php, shell

Following code executes in php,

```
shell_exec('echo '.$passkey.' | sudo -u '.$user.' -S sh '.$shellfile.' 2>&1');
```

Basic shell file,

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello"
```

The shell command alone returns `Password:hello` as expected on the first run (returns "hello" after "Password" prompt).

shell_exec return the following error,

> Password:Sorry, try again.
> Password:
> sudo: no password was provided
> sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt

Need help to understand where or what the issue is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522979/php-shell-exec-with-sudo-commands-not-working